# How to validate HTML select tag without javascript

Tags: html, forms

Our select tags display an empty option tag at the beginning to ensure users don't automatically select the first option otherwise displayed:

```
<select name="title" required pattern="[A-Z]">
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Ms">Ms</option>
</select>
```

How do we validate the select tag to ensure one of the options OTHER than 0 is selected?

Perferably without Javascript!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `value=""` for the first option and the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-required) validation will behave as expected:

```html
<form>
  <select name="title" required>
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="1">First Value</option>
  </select>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

<sub>Keep in mind [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms) when leveraging HTML5 form validation.</sub>